Why do some Kiddush cups have golden dome accents on them?
When shopping for Kiddush cups, I find a lot of them have golden domes on them, such as this one from a popular Judaica store:

I am confused by the golden dome accents in the cups artwork. As far as I am aware the only golden dome in Jerusalem is the dome of the rock.
Are the domes on this cup representative of something else, maybe a historical architecture? Why would a Jewish store put these golden domes on their cups?

I don't know the exact origins of this, but many drawings and paintings of Jerusalem feature domed houses and other structures (rather than angled roofs). The gold looks nice against the silver.

question aside, that's a beautiful kiddush cup!

Are you specifically asking about gold domes, or domes in general? Jerusalem has lots of domes, even today, especially the old city. They are not gold, usually white, sandstone or blue
